# Find the probability that X lies within one standard deviation of the mean.

Tags: probability-distributions

> The random variable X has a Poisson distribution with mean $μ=5.55$. Find the probability that X lies within one standard deviation of the mean.

Using my calculator, I found $P(3.19<X<7.9)$ where $3.19 = 5.55 - \sqrt{5.55}$ and $7.9 = 5.55 + \sqrt{5.55}$ and got $0.683$.

The answer shows:

[image]

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: How did you get $0.683$?

Comment: normalcdf($5.55 - \sqrt{5.55}$, $5.55 + \sqrt{5.55}$, $5.55$, $\sqrt{5.55}$)

Comment: The question said it's a Poisson distribution and you have calculated a normal distribution.

Comment: My bad...Thanks for spotting it.